# 3-dB Frequency of second order transfer function

Tags: filter, transfer-function, bandwidth, cutoff-frequency, frequency-response

[image]

How can i obtain the 3db frequency of the each transfer function ?

My attempt:

My guess is both transfer functions have the same 3db frequency.But equating the magnitude to 0.707 gives a fourth order equation which can be reduced to second order to obtain square of 3db frequency.

However, i am not able to simplify it.The exact expression however is as follows:

[image]

Is there any approximate approach for obtaining the same?

Comment: For G1(s), write the numerator as 'b'

Comment: just need to be careful as dc gain is 1/b right? i tuk that into account while calculating .

Comment: It's 4th order, but reduces to 2nd order if you let \$\omega^2=\Omega\$. Then factorises easily.

Comment: does factor,but not into a simple expression , there will be quadratic terms under the root thou

Comment: Are you wanting the 3 dB bandwidth when both TFs are multiplied?

Comment: no its just that both give same 3db frequency,one is an LPF and the other is a HPF

Comment: Square the root, then do the substitution, then solve the quadratic. Couldn't be much easier!

Comment: solving it doesnt take it to the solution i have put up,else i wudnt have posted this at first place

Comment: Why do you think it's a HPF?

Comment: Oops i have been a little sloppy there ,thanks for pointing it out,lets consider it a general case scenario

Comment: Re-write the question, then

Comment: yea already done

Comment: Please read my comment - I'm confused as to what you want.

Comment: @Andyaka  , i need the 3db frequency of the two transfer functions mentioned.

Comment: Write the original question in full, rather than giving what you think it's asking.

Comment: As one big combined TF or as individual TFs?

Comment: of individual TFs @Andyaka

Comment: @Chu i have made the question clear

Comment: 'the exact expression is as follows...'. Firstly, it's not an expression; and secondly, where has it come from?

Comment: it would be nice to use \$\LaTeX\$ for your math.  \$G_1(s)\$ is a low-pass filter and has a single -3 dB point.  \$G_2(s)\$ is a band-pass filter and has two -3 dB points.  you find the -3 dB frequencies, also called *"half-power frequencies"* by substituting \$s \leftarrow j\omega\$ and evaluating \$|G_1(j\omega)|^2\$ and \$|G_2(j\omega)|^2\$, setting those expressions to \$\frac12 |G_1(0)|^2\$ or \$\frac12 |G_2(j\omega_0)|^2\$ where \$\omega_0\$ is the resonant frequency of the BPF (which, in your case happens to be \$\omega_0 = \sqrt{b}\$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I show you how to obtain the 3dB cut-off frequency for the low pass filter \$G_1(s)\$. You can calculate the cut-off frequencies of the band pass filter \$G_2(s)\$ in a similar way, as long as you know that its maximum magnitude is attained at \$\omega=\sqrt{b}\$, as pointed out in a comment by robert bristow-johnson. The latter fact can be derived by setting the derivative of \$|G_2(j\omega)|^2\$ to zero. (Note that \$b>0\$ is always satisfied for \$G_1(s)\$ and \$G_2(s)\$ to be transfer functions of causal and stable filters.)

To compute the 3dB cut-off frequency of \$G_1(s)\$ you have to solve

$$|G_1(j\omega)|^2=\frac{|G(0)|^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2b^2}\tag{1}$$

With

$$G_1(j\omega)=\frac{1}{-\omega^2+ja\omega+b}\tag{2}$$

you get

$$|G_1(j\omega)|^2=\frac{1}{(b-\omega^2)^2+a^2\omega^2}\tag{3}$$

Plugging (3) into (1) gives

$$(b-\omega^2)^2+a^2\omega^2=2b^2\tag{4}$$

With the substitution \$x=\omega^2\$, you get the following quadratic equation

$$x^2+(a^2-2b)x-b^2=0\tag{5}$$

with the positive solution

$$x_0=b-\frac{a^2}{2}+\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^2+b^2}\tag{6}$$

From (6), the value of the 3dB cut-off frequency is

$$\omega_c=\sqrt{x_0}=\sqrt{b-\frac{a^2}{2}+\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{a^2}{2}\right)^2+b^2}}\tag{7}$$